# How use JSF 2.0 f:ajax option with .jsp pages

Tags: java, jsf-2

Due to yet FusionCharts is not support for acelets, I should have to use .jsp page for my dashboard.

```
 <h:commandLink value="next &gt;" styleClass="paginationLink">
                        <f:ajax event="click" execute="taskSeaResults" render="taskSeaResults" listener="#{homeController.homePageNavigator.next}"/>
                    </h:commandLink>
```

Then when I try to use f:ajax option as above in that dashboard.jsp it was not working, I have included the taglib also (<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>). Is there any alternative way to accomplish this f:ajax functionality with .jsp pages? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

JSP is [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) since JSF 2.0. All tags which are new since JSF 2.0 are not available for JSP anymore. Move on to Facelets.

Comment: does it make since that new components like `h:inputFile` works in .jsp page ? because that worked with me while f:ajax didn't